# T-SQL using OpenRowSet to read BulkColumn in nvarchar

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm having issues getting `@jsonText` to include special characters such as the spanish n. I believe this is because the `SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET` returns the blob in a `varchar` format. I tried changing `@json_Out` to take `nvarchar(MAX)` but that causes an error when I use `OPENJSON` on `@jsonText`

```
/* Dynamically read json path from i/p variable and perform the openrowset process */
DECLARE @jsonText NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Command NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Param_Def NVARCHAR(500),
        @FileVar NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @json_Out VARCHAR(MAX);


SET @FileVar = '\\s\storage\root\Health\To_ODS\IDC\Queue\92.json';
SET @Param_Def = N'@JSON_FILE NVARCHAR(MAX), @json_Out varchar(MAX) OUTPUT';
SET @Command = N'SELECT @json_Out = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + '\\s\storage\root\Health\To_ODS\IDC\Queue\92.json' + N''', SINGLE_BLOB, CODEPAGE=''65001'') ROW_SET';

EXEC sp_executesql @Command,
                   @Param_Def,
                   @JSON_FILE = @FileVar,
                   @json_Out = @jsonText OUTPUT;

SELECT * FROM openjson(@jsonText)
```

Comment: You cannot combine `SINGLE_BLOB` and `CODEPAGE`; the server will ignore the `CODEPAGE` directive and return a single `VARBINARY(MAX)`, which will then be interpreted as a string (which will always fail, as current versions of SQL Server do not support UTF-8 for in-engine strings). The least painful way to do is is to save the file in UTF-16 and use the `SINGLE_NCLOB` option. Alternatively, create a temp table with a single column and use `BULK INSERT ... WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char', CODEPAGE='65001')`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks. I actually don't use the CODEPAGE in the current production flow, that was just me trying different things to see if it would fix it. I tried looking into saving the file in UTF-16 but it seems very complicted (not able to do in Notepad++?) Could you elaborate/assist on the alternative temp table solution?

Comment: In Notepad++, you can change the encoding with "Encoding -> Encode in UCS-2 BE BOM" and SQL Server will accept that. The temp table solution is `CREATE TABLE #json([json] NVARCHAR(MAX)); BULK INSERT #json FROM '<path>' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='char', CODEPAGE='65001'); SELECT @jsonText = [json] FROM #json`.